# Calendar.getInstance gives wrong date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I create few small methods as an Util class, like the following code:

```
public class Util
{
  public static final String DATETIME_PATTERN="YYYY/MM/DD - HH:mm:ss";

  public static String getDateTime()
  {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat(DATETIME_PATTERN);
    return sdf.format(getToday());
  }

  public static Date getToday()
  {
    //Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance(); //didn't help
    Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.TAIWAN); //didn't fix
    //Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+08:00")); //didn't fix as well
    return today.getTime();
  }
}
```

And, did a very simple run, like this:

```
//run in main class
System.out.println("Generating sitemap.xml, please wait..."+Util.getDateTime());
```

The result is a quite weird date -> 2017/07/**187**

```
//Console result:
Generating sitemap.xml, please wait...2017/07/187 - 15:27:21
```

Searched for similar question, and tried TimeZone, Locale, but didn't help.
Any suggestions ?

---

BTW, here's my environment:

- Windows7 x86
- JDK 1.8.0.131 x86
- eclipse oxygen x86

Comment: Try using small case letters for the DD; so test: "YYYY/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss";

Comment: You should start by reading the documentation of the classes you are using: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: When using Java 8 (and even if you didn’t), throw the outdated classes `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` overboard and start using the modern and much nicer Java date and time API.

Comment: @Luftbaum, you’re on the right track, but you also need lowercase `yyyy`.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting. You would have found hundreds of examples of code to compare to yours to identify the fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with the way you are formatting the date.
Try changing it to this

```
  public static final String DATETIME_PATTERN="yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss";
```

Answer (score 5):

[James Owen’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946427/5772882) is correct: you need to use lowercase `yyyy` and lowercase `dd` in your format pattern string. That should do it.

What I want to contribute here is the modern and improved version of your utility class:

```
public class Util
{
    public static final String DATETIME_PATTERN = "yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss";

    public static String getDateTime()
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATETIME_PATTERN);
        return getNow().format(dtf);
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime getNow()
    {
        return ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Taipei"));
    }
}
```

Since you are using Java 8, there is no reason for you to take the trouble with the long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. The modern classes are generally much nicer to work with. I took the freedom of also returning a bit more information from `getToday()` (and renamed it to `getNow`): it now tells you both the current time and the time zone, which makes sure that `getDateTime()` also formats the time in this time zone.

I preferred `Asia/Taipei` as time zone. It gives the same result as `GMT+08:00`, but (1) is futureproof in case Taiwan again introduces summer time (DST) (2) is clearer to read and tells the reader more about why this particular offset was chosen (Taiwan has had summer time before, last time was in 1979).

### An example of the trouble with `SimpleDateFormat`

One out of many objections to the old classes is they tend to pretend everything is well when it isn’t. You got an incorrect output and no explanation why. You would have preferred some error message. The modern classes behave a bit better on this point. Say you had used your pattern string with my code. It gives

> java.time.DateTimeException: Field DayOfYear cannot be printed as the
>   value 187 exceeds the maximum print width of 2

Day of year? You may have to check [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see that capital `D` is for day-of-year while small `d` is for day-of-month. Let’s fix:

```
public static final String DATETIME_PATTERN = "YYYY/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss";
```

Unfortunately `DateTimeFormatter` does not catch your other error, the uppercase `YYYY`. This means week-based year and is only useful with a week number. But theoretically you might have intended this, the class has no chance to tell. If you had tried to parse with the same format, you would have been told you couldn’t.

### If you need a `Date`

Maybe you need a `Date` object for some legacy API that you cannot change. In Java 8 the old classes have been fitted with conversion methods, so it’s easy (when you know how). You may for example add this method:

```
public static Date getNowAsOldfashionedDateObject() {
    return Date.from(getNow().toInstant());
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer